# How to make user interface with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I want to build complex JavaFX application that will be used for editing database tables. I need advice how to build the user interface - using FXML for visual layout or using the Java API and manually make the user interface? But is there a design tool that I can use to build the interface using the Java API?

Comment: Netbeans? [this](https://netbeans.org/features/java-on-client/javafx.html) and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/jfxpub-get_started.htm) for example?

Answer (score 3):

To the design some FXML layouts I would take the [Oracles JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html).

Which option you should take depends on your experience. I've had good experiences with both techniques and prefer the FXML method.
Because I worked a lot with JSF and secondly the separation between UI and data management is very good.

Comment: Just to add an update (came here through a duplicate link): Scene Builder is no longer maintained by Oracle. It is currently maintained by Gluon and download links can be found [here](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).